# MongoDB finding set differences

Tags: mongodb, set, compare, pipeline, aggregation

What would be the best way to compare one attribute from two collections to find which ones are missing?

I have two collections "items" and "items_recovery"
items look like this

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("64789354c78b2fd7db3ebea"),
  item_name: 'BIKE_1032_HE_files/17/1_45',
...
}

db> db.items_recovery.find().count()
6174859
db> db.items.find().count()
6362241
```

there are indices in `item_name`

What would be the best way to know which ones I am missing in the recovery collection using an aggregation pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple `$lookup` to find the documents already having a recovery. Then, you can deduce the documents without recovery because they have 0 matching recovery.

Here an example of how you could implement that :

```
db.item.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "item_recovery",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$project": {
            _id: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "hasRecovery"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $size: "$hasRecovery"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "hasRecovery"
  }
])
```

You can test this solution on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mwBXE6z-qgW)

Comment: My thought is similar to you. I just use `$limit: 1` in the sub pipeline to limit the number of returned documents like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hx1z65vTFjj)

Comment: but does this actually create an attribute in the items collection, only to unset it later? Also another question, the local and foreign field is  actually item_name, do I use it in  the $project stage?

Comment: An `aggregate` is like a query but with various operator. It does NOT update the collection in anyway (exception for operator like `$out`). So, no, it does not create an attribute in the collection.
For the local/foreign field, you should update them with `item_name` if this is your unique reference between the two collection. The `$project` stage itself is not mandatory, it was to limit data processed by the query. Adding or removing things from the `$project` stage will have no impact. You could even remove the whole `pipeline` and its content.